# Android Hide FAB menu when unfocused

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, floating-action-button

I have a Floating Action Button with a custom menu of mini Floating Action Buttons, that appears upon click on the main Floating Action Button.
The mini FABs are in a LinearLayout.

I want that after opening the FAB menu, when the user clicks elsewhere, the menu disappears. However, I haven't been able to find how to do this.
What listener do I need for this?

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you done so far that isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely interested in a custom `FloatingActionButton.Behavior`:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.Behavior.html

https://medium.com/@nullthemall/floatingactionmenu-floatingactionbutton-behavior-dd33cc0d9ba7#.jsvuvz2rk

Otherwise you can simply set the `Visibility` of the respective controls to `Gone` based on a `OnTouchListener` that checks if you are touching outside the `FAB`.

Comment: Thanks. How do I check via a OnTouchListener if I'm touching outside the FAB?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446855/ontouchlistener-intercept-when-touch-goes-outside-view

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685690/android-make-view-disappear-by-clicking-outside-of-it